# unsafe javascript attempt to access frame on local files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an application that creates HTML for users to view on their local machines (not hosted as a website).  This currently works fine with IE & FireFox but Chrome does not like that I am using Frames that interact with each other (So a Navigation frame that when you click on an item I then load a new html file into a content frame).  Chrome gives me the unsafe javascript attempt - Domains must match etc.  So I've created a small example that has all the required files in the same directory (and should be within the same Domain?), but I still get the issue.

My example code has 2 iFrames within a starting html page, the 1st iFrame has a button that will change the source of the 2nd iFrame - fairly straight forward.

I've tried using the sandbox attributes but these have not helped.

So here's my code:

**start.htm**

```
<body>
  <iframe id="fheader" src="NewHeader.htm" name="fheader" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin   allow-forms allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
  <iframe id="fbody" src="BodyLime.htm" name="fbody" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
</body>
```

**header.htm**

```
function myClick() {

   var myFrame = parent.document.getElementById("fbody");  

   myFrame.setAttribute("src", "BodyRed.htm");

}

<body style="background-color:Aqua">    
    <input id="Button1" onclick="myClick()" type="button" value="Change your neighbours colour"/>    
</body>
```

BodyRed.htm and BodyLime.htm are just simple pages with the background colour set to show if the code works.

I've also tried access the frames with the code below but as soon as I try to access any attributes of the frame I get the same error:

```
  var myfbody = parent.fbody;
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Perhaps `sanbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` will help you.

Comment: Well you can have your users open Chrome in kiosk mode `chrome url --kiosk` or `chrome --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d) --kiosk`

Comment: Already have the allow-scripts and the allow-same-origin set in my example.

Comment: And can't really ask users to run their browsers with switches set, some of my users have pretty locked down settings on their browsers due to admin policies.